# How can I expire entries to Django database cache?

Tags: python, django, django-cache

I have a Django application with a registered database cache:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'exchange_rate_cache',
    }
}
```

I want the entries in my cache to expire and be deleted after a week. To delete an entry from the cache all that is needed is the following:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.delete(key)
```

However I must only perform this if the entry has been stored in cache for longer than 1 week.

How can this be done? Thank you.

Comment: In the cache, you can set an expiration time.

Comment: How can this be done though?

Comment: redis_time_cache = 180
cache.set(key, data, redis_time_cache)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you solve the problem at the wrong level: the `CACHES` settings **have** a setting for *automatic* expiration: the [**`'TIMEOUT'`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#cache-arguments) key:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'exchange_rate_cache',
        'TIMEOUT': 604800  # 7 days
    }
}
```

This settings speicifies the number of seconds before the value "expires", or as said in the [documentation [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#cache-arguments):

> `TIMEOUT`: The default timeout, in seconds, to use for the cache. This
>   argument **defaults to 300 seconds (5 minutes)**. You can set `TIMEOUT` to
>   `None` so that, by default, cache keys never expire. A value of `0` causes
>   keys to immediately expire (effectively “don’t cache”).

A day takes *60×60×24* seconds, and a *week* is *7* days, so a week has, `604800` seconds.

By adding this in the settings, you can easily change the expiration if you later change your mind.

A cache by default also holds a limited number of elements (see other settings in the documentation), and furthermore there other things can cause the cache to remove elements (for example if you use a *memory cache* restarting the server will normally clear the cache).

Furthermore you can - like [@marin says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51948769/67579) - also *ad-hoc* specify an expiration for a specific key when you `set(..)` it; as is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#basic-usage):

> The basic interface is `set(key, value, timeout)` and `get(key)`
>
> (..)
>
> The `timeout` argument is optional and **defaults to the `timeout`
>   argument of the appropriate backend in the `CACHES` setting**
>   (explained above). It’s the number of seconds the value should be
>   stored in the cache. Passing in `None` for `timeout` will cache the
>   value forever. A timeout of 0 won’t cache the value.

Comment: Any clue on whether django culls records from the database itself? or does this need to be done manually?

Comment: :( I only want to expire a small subset of all the records. Specifically, I want to expire fields in a record when any sibling record changes (added/removed/edited). That's the only time a cache ever needs to refresh in my case...

Comment: Does that mean Django data base cache will delete entries from actual db after expiry or its just the runtime check of expiry time?

Answer (score 3):

```
redis_time_cache = 180 # seconds
cache.set(key, data, redis_time_cache)
```

1. key = 'my_key'
2. data = JSON or STRING
3. redis_time_cache = TIMEOUT

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other cache backends, the database cache does not support automatic culling of expired entries at the database level. Instead, expired cache entries are culled each time add(), set(), or touch() is called.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#database-caching

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).